# Find all newline character index in string js

Tags: javascript

I have a string contains some newline character and I want to find all indexes of the newline character in the string.

```
asdfasdfhkjashfkjhas
adfdsfasdfdsfa
dfdfasdfsdfasgsadfasdfasdfdsfasdfasdfasdfasdfas
dfasdfasfsdfasdfsadfdsaffgasfasfd0sa
fdsafdasfsadfdfhasdkfjhasdlkfhlaskdjhflaksdjfhaskldjfhkljja
dfsadsadfawsefasdffasdfasdgaasdfajfalskdkjflkjslkdfj
lkasdjflksdajflksadjkflksdfdsfsdfasdfddhfkjasdhjkfhkjfhakjsdhfkjsadhfk
jdsbfjgasdkjfhkjasdhgfbjhsadgfjhsdfksdgfjkhdfjkh
```

My code

```
const findNewLineCharacterIndex = (s) => {
    let l = 0; let r = s.length - 1;
    const arr = [];
    const cmp = (char) => char === '\n' || char === '\r';
    while (l < r) {
        if (cmp(s[l])) arr.push(l);
        if (cmp(s[r])) arr.push(r);
        l += 1;
        r -= 1;
    }
    arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    return arr;
};
```

```js
const str = `asdfasdfhkjashfkjhas
adfdsfasdfdsfa
dfdfasdfsdfasgsadfasdfasdfdsfasdfasdfasdfasdfas
dfasdfasfsdfasdfsadfdsaffgasfasfd0sa
fdsafdasfsadfdfhasdkfjhasdlkfhlaskdjhflaksdjfhaskldjfhkljja
dfsadsadfawsefasdffasdfasdgaasdfajfalskdkjflkjslkdfj
lkasdjflksdajflksadjkflksdfdsfsdfasdfddhfkjasdhjkfhkjfhakjsdhfkjsadhfk
jdsbfjgasdkjfhkjasdhgfbjhsadgfjhsdfksdgfjkhdfjkh`

const findNewLineCharacterIndex = (s) => {
    let l = 0; let r = s.length - 1;
    const arr = [];
    const cmp = (char) => char === '\n' || char === '\r';
    while (l < r) {
        if (cmp(s[l])) arr.push(l);
        if (cmp(s[r])) arr.push(r);
        l += 1;
        r -= 1;
    }
    arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    return arr;
};

console.log(findNewLineCharacterIndex(str));
```

the result index is `[34, 82, 119, 179, 232, 303, 352]`, but what i expected is `[20,34, 82, 119, 179, 232, 303, 352]` (index 20 is lost).

I tried with just 1 newline and the result is empty.

I tried with `indexOf`, it shown the first index 20 but i want to find all.

How can I improve this ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

That looks quite complicated to me. I think it'd be simpler and less error-prone to turn the string into an array, then just `forEach` over it, pushing the index when the character matches.

```js
const s = `a
bcd
efgh
ijklmn
`;
const findNewLineCharacterIndex = (s) => {
    const indicies = [];
    [...s].forEach((char, i) => {
        if (char === '\n' || char === '\r') indicies.push(i);
    });
    return indicies;
};
console.log(findNewLineCharacterIndex(s));
```

Less code means less surface area for bugs.

Comment: I'd use a regex and loop over the results

Answer (score 0):

Simple `for loop` is also enough to do the task.

```js
const str = `asdfasdfhkjashfkjhas
adfdsfasdfdsfa
dfdfasdfsdfasgsadfasdfasdfdsfasdfasdfasdfasdfas
dfasdfasfsdfasdfsadfdsaffgasfasfd0sa
fdsafdasfsadfdfhasdkfjhasdlkfhlaskdjhflaksdjfhaskldjfhkljja
dfsadsadfawsefasdffasdfasdgaasdfajfalskdkjflkjslkdfj
lkasdjflksdajflksadjkflksdfdsfsdfasdfddhfkjasdhjkfhkjfhakjsdhfkjsadhfk
jdsbfjgasdkjfhkjasdhgfbjhsadgfjhsdfksdgfjkhdfjkh`;

const findNewLineCharacterIndex = (s) => {
   const indexList = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i] === "\n" || s[i] === "\r") {
      indexList.push(i);
    }
   }
   return indexList;
};

console.log(findNewLineCharacterIndex(str));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const str = `asdfasdfhkjashfkjhas
adfdsfasdfdsfa
dfdfasdfsdfasgsadfasdfasdfdsfasdfasdfasdfasdfas
dfasdfasfsdfasdfsadfdsaffgasfasfd0sa
fdsafdasfsadfdfhasdkfjhasdlkfhlaskdjhflaksdjfhaskldjfhkljja
dfsadsadfawsefasdffasdfasdgaasdfajfalskdkjflkjslkdfj
lkasdjflksdajflksadjkflksdfdsfsdfasdfddhfkjasdhjkfhkjfhakjsdhfkjsadhfk
jdsbfjgasdkjfhkjasdhgfbjhsadgfjhsdfksdgfjkhdfjkh`;

let i=0;
for(i=0;i<str.length;i++)
{
    if(str[i]=='\n')
    {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
console.log(i);
```

Shouldn't it be done easily like this? also, the newline comes at index [20,35,83,120,180,233,304,353]

Comment: As you can see from the previous answers to this question '\r' is also a newline character. Your answer unfortunately does not add any new insights to those already given.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.